# How to get boolean user input using scanner?

Tags: java, input, boolean

So i have to ask the user whether they are above 18 and they have to answer with a true or false. And keep looping until they enter the right input

So far, i have this

```
boolean b = false;
do {
    try {
        System.out.print("Are you above 18?");
        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean bn = s.nextBoolean();

        if (bn == true) {
            // do stuff
        } else if (bn == false) {
            // do stuff
        }

    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input!");
    }
} while (!b);
```

HOWEVER, it wont work as the loop keeps going and it wont read the input right and do my if statements. How do i fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I will go with `y/n` option in this case.

Comment: `bn == true` is redundant. `bn` evaluates to a boolean value.

Comment: Are you setting your `b` variable to `true` inside one of your conditions? Your loop won't stop until `b` is `true` and it's not reference anywhere in your loop. Did you mean to do while `(!bn)`?.

Comment: Just off the topic, replace your `if(bn == true)` with `if(bn)`.

Comment: What input values have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**slight tweak to your program. This works**

```
boolean b = false;
        do {
            try {
                System.out.print("Are you above 18?");
                Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
                boolean bn = n.nextBoolean();
                if (bn == true) {
                    System.out.println("Over 18");
                } else if (bn == false) {
                    System.out.println("under 18");
                }

            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input!");
            }
        } while (!b);
```

**And the output is**

```
Are you above 18?true
Over 18
Are you above 18?false
under 18
Are you above 18?
```

Comment: Just formatted it. Indentations were little off. :) Not sure if that's what was your question?

Answer (score 2):

You need to re-check your Scanner statement and Initializing statement...

```
Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean bn = s.nextBoolean();
```

It should be

```
Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean bn = n.nextBoolean();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
boolean bn = s.nextBoolean();
```

to

```
b = s.nextBoolean();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use-

> scanner.nextBoolean()

```
    do{
      try{
          System.out.print("Are you above 18?");
          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
          if(scanner.nextBoolean()==true)
           //do stuff

          }else{

          //do stuff
          }
       }
```